# How does this parallel assignment with the splat operator work in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

```
letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
first, *second = letters
first  # => "a"
second # => "["b", "c", "d", "e"]
```

I understand what this produces, but can't get my head around this. Is this basically Ruby magic? Can't think of any other programming language that would support this type of assignment with the splat operator.

Answer (score 3):

This is quite a common thing in functional languages, so Ruby is not alone. You have a list of items and want it separated in a `head` and a `tail`, so you can perform an operation on the first element of the list.

This also works:

```
letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
first, *middle, last = letters
```

In a functional language like Clojure, you would see something like:

```
(first '(1 2 3)) => 1
(rest '(1 2 3)) => (2 3)
```

Comment: +1 for the reference to FP, though it may worth noting that in FP you have linked lists, so extracting head and tail from them is a cheap operation. With arrays it's not so cheap unfortunately...

Answer (score 3):

This is a very interesting thing here is described in great detail all the ["magical properties"](http://po-ru.com/diary/destructuring-assignment-in-ruby/)

for example

```
a, *b, c = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
a # => 1
b # => [2, 3, 4]
c # => 5

a, (b, c) = [2,[2,[6,7]]]
a
=> 2
b
=> 2
c
=> [6, 7]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it basically creates an array. Look at the following example:

```
> *foo = 1
> foo
 => [1]
```

So here `*second` will create an array and extract all elements from `letters[1..-1]`. Otherwise it would just assign `letters[1]`, which is `"b"` to the `second` variable.

I'm sure someone will come up with a better explanation, but the basic idea is here.

More information about the [splat operator](http://endofline.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/the-strange-ruby-splat/).