# how do I extract the substrings between underscores from the following string "hold_sim_D_C3_1_one_aoi" using Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have a string and I want to get the substrings between the underscores.

Example input string: hold_sim_D_C3_1_one_aoi

desired output substrings: sim, D, C3, 1, one

Comment: provide example input and desired output.

Comment: There is still no expected output. You should provide a valid Ruby object as the expect output

Comment: is the question clear now?

Comment: Question is still unclear. `puts 'hold_sim_D_C3_1_one_aoi'.split('_')`

Comment: Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages, "[mcve]" and “[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)". We'd like to see evidence of your effort. What did you try? Did you search and not find anything? Did you find stuff but it didn't help? Did you try writing code? If not, why? If so, what is the smallest code example that shows what you tried and why didn't it work? Without that it looks like you didn't try and want us to write it for you.

Comment: I have been trying using regex but I missed the simple solution provided by Andrey Deineko.

Comment: Please, make sure to ***read*** what @theTinMan wrote. It is essential.

Comment: I will. Thanks @Andrey Deineko.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`split`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-split) with [splat assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19705092/how-does-this-parallel-assignment-with-the-splat-operator-work-in-ruby) in order to ignore the first and last words :

```
head, *words, tail = "hold_sim_D_C3_1_one_aoi".split('_')
p words
#=> ["sim", "D", "C3", "1", "one"]
```

If you don't need `head` or `tail`, you could use either :

```
_, *words, _ = "hold_sim_D_C3_1_one_aoi".split('_')
```

or

```
words = "hold_sim_D_C3_1_one_aoi".split('_')[1..-2]
```

`words` will be an empty array when the string contains less than 2 underscores.

Since you tried with a Regex, you could use [positive lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) :

```
"hold_sim_D_C3_1_one_aoi".scan(/(?<=_).*?(?=_)/)
#=> ["sim", "D", "C3", "1", "one"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers @Eric Duminil

Comment: There's no point creating variables that only serve to pollute the variable space.  I'd recommend using `words = '...'.split('_')[1 .. -2]` rather than create `head` and `tail` that have to be thrown away anyway. Instead of `head, *words, tail` you could use `_, *words, _` but that just creates visual noise.

Comment: @theTinMan: It's true that it pollutes the variable space, but I do find the first variant easier to read and understand, though. I thought about `_`, but that might have confused OP since we split around `'_'`. Anyway, answer has been updated.